# Is there a free API to pull current TPS?

Tags: api

Has someone created an API for TPS and other blockchain metrics (Solana)?

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Sammy's answer, this is how you request & calculate the TPS:

```
// Request
curl https://ssc-dao.genesysgo.net -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {"jsonrpc":"2.0", "id":1, "method":"getRecentPerformanceSamples", "params": [1]}
'
```

Then do:
`numTransactions / samplePeriodSecs`
and you will get TPS :)

Comment: Expanding on Harry's expansion (lol), if you wanted to do this with web3.js, there's a handy dandy method that shares the same name: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getRecentPerformanceSamples

ex: 
`let samples: PerfSample[] = await connection.getRecentPerformanceSamples();`

Comment: could just pipe it to `jq` ala, `jq '.result[0] | .numTransactions / .samplePeriodSecs'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the getRecentPerformanceSamples JSON RPC API call. That will return data that you'd be able to use to estimate TPS and a couple other metrics. This is what the Solana Explorer uses (along with many other dApps).

https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getrecentperformancesamples